# Ubuntu 19.10 Super + Q to show dock and number overlay not working

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 19.10, dock

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 19.10 and I've noticed that the command Super + Q for showing the dock and the number overlay is not working.

I've tried dconf Editor, remapping the "shortcut" and "shortcut-text" under `org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/` to different combinations and it's still not working

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:**

Here's the output from:

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 sebastian sebastian 4096 mar 15 21:06 .
drwx------ 3 sebastian sebastian 4096 mar 15 21:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 sebastian sebastian 4096 mar 15 21:06 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
```

And the output from:

```
ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 oct 17 09:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 mar 14 21:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 oct 17 09:27 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 oct 17 09:27 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mar 14 21:34 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Do you have `Dash to Dock` GNOME Shell extension installed?

Comment: Yes, with or without that extension, still not working

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: You have to let me know if/when you respond with requested data, or I'll miss it. Start comments to me with @heynnema. If you log into a different user account, does it work properly there? Report back.

Comment: @heynnema nope, not working, just created a new account, installed ```Dash to Dock``` again and still not working

Comment: Oops. You weren't supposed to have installed DtD in that other account. It interacts with the existing dock extension supplied with Ubuntu. Please create another temporary NEW account, don't install ANYTHING there, and try a virgin account, and see if it works as expected.

Comment: @heynnema sorry, what I did was: first, created an account, then tried "Super + Q " normally, as it worked in Ubuntu 18.04 (without installing any extensions) and no luck, then I installed ```Dash to Dock``` and tried again, still not working

Comment: Try, in `terminal`, `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys true`, or use `dconf`, then restart GNOME Shell, or log out/in, or reboot.

Comment: @heynnema tried that, still not working. BTW installed ```Dash to Dock``` version is 67 (lastest)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105651/discussion-between-sebastian-and-heynnema).